# how to change <img src> with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a Javascript function that I been dealing with for a few hours,

Javascript:

```
var musicFile = new Audio('audio/Ice.mp3');
var audioState = document.getElementById('musicIcon');

function music() {
    if (audioState.src = 'images/musicOff.svg') {
        musicFile.play();
        audioState.src = 'images/musicOn.svg';
    } else if(audioState.src = 'images/musicOn.svg') {
        musicFile.pause();
        musicFile.currentTime = 0;
        audioState.src = 'images/musicOff.svg';
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul class="tabs" style="top: 0px; right: 0px; width: 210px; right: 10px; text-shadow: 1px 1px indigo;">
    <li class="tab" onclick="music()">
        <img id="musicIcon" src="images/musicOff.svg" width="32" height="32">
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.tabs {
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 800px;
    height: 30px;
}
.tab {
    position: relative;
    top: 30%;
    width: 15%;
    height: 20px;
    background:royalblue;
    border: 0px transparent;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: monospace;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;

}
.tab:hover {
    text-align:center;
    background-color: #CCC;
}
```

The `<li>` tag is meant to act as a button, and it does everything in the function, (changes .svg Icon and plays the music) but the second time I click it again, nothing happens. I also checked the console, and no errors.

I would really appreciate some help, and maybe some tips in general. (New to Javascript, not looking to use jQuery right now.)

Comment: What happens if you change the "else if" to an "else" and remove its conditional?

Comment: @RyanMillares , The exact same thing happens, I already tried this a while ago, i believe it was the first thing I tried.

Comment: can you try putting a console.log() in your else if to check if it is running that block?

Comment: @RyanMillares Just tried it, nothing seems to happen at all, and nothing is being logged to the console

Comment: I see, can you try adding an else { after your 'else if' block and place this in it: console.log(String(audioState.src)), to check what it is reading in as the current src during the second click?

Comment: You need double equal signs `==` to compare values; you are using single equal signs `=` instead, which is for assignment, e.g. `if (audioState.src == 'images/musicOff.svg') {`.

Comment: @HorseBob see Decent Dabbler's comment, that is correct. The reason it works once is because it sees the assignment in the if statement and performs the action. Since the action didn't break, it'll successfully run the if block. However, since your else if is not using "==", it'll never run it

Comment: I tried double equal signs for both if and else if, nothing happened that time, also I did the `console.log(String(audioState.src))` suggested, if I did double equal signs for the first If statement, it went to the else, and logged it? But if I did a single equal sign, it wouldn't do the else statement, but did everything else

Comment: Ideally, have two different buttons and show/hide them.

Comment: @RyanMillares Hey, I'll try actually look at my code again, I didn't know about the needing of those, I'll come back after doing some more testing

Comment: @HorseBob try "===" instead then, that is my preferred operator for comparison in js

Comment: I tried every single comparison that you all have suggested, I'll keep in mind all the suggestions, I'll come back after maybe rewriting my code, maybe I just need to trace back my steps and see if I messed up somewhere else

Comment: Another thing is, that `audioState.src` will return the full URI of the source, so comparing it to relative URIs such as `'images/musicOff.svg'` will not yield a match.

Comment: @DecentDabbler I'll keep that in mind, thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you're forgetting to use double equals to do a comparation. Change `=` to `==`

`audioState.src` is returning absolute path, try change it for the method `getAttribute('src')` on all comparations. like that:

```
audioState.getAttribute('src') == 'images/musicOff.svg'
```

and to change `src` value, try to use `setAttribute('attribute', 'newValue')` method
like that:

```
audioState.setAttribute('src', 'images/musicOff.svg');
```

hope it help u

Comment: getAttribute isn't necessary, src is a reflected property documented supported by every browser (i think)

Comment: This worked! Thanks for the suggestion, It'll definitely come in handy in the future!

Answer (score 3):

There's a couple of things going on with your example:

1. To compare values your need to either use double `==` (loose comparison) or triple `===` (strict comparison) equal signs.
2. It might be that you are calling `var audioState = document.getElementById('musicIcon');` too early, because the document has not been fully parsed yet, and so `audioState` will be `null`, instead of the element.
3. `audioState.src` will return the full URI to the source after you have assigned a value to it. So comparing it to the relative URI will not match.

Here's a working example, putting it all together (I left out the audio file part):

```js
var audioState;
// create absolute URIs from relative URIs of the images, resolved against document.documentURI
var imageOffUri = new URL('images/musicOff.svg', document.documentURI);
var imageOnUri = new URL('images/musicOn.svg', document.documentURI);
function music() {
    if (audioState.src == imageOffUri) {
        audioState.src = imageOnUri;
        console.log('turned on');
    } else if(audioState.src == imageOnUri) {
        audioState.src = imageOffUri;
        console.log('turned off');
    }
}

// wait for the document to be fully parsed
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  audioState = document.getElementById('musicIcon');
});
```

```css
.tabs {
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 800px;
    height: 30px;
}
.tab {
    position: relative;
    top: 30%;
    width: 15%;
    height: 20px;
    background:royalblue;
    border: 0px transparent;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: monospace;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;

}
.tab:hover {
    text-align:center;
    background-color: #CCC;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <ul class="tabs" style="top: 0px; right: 0px; width: 210px; right: 10px; text-shadow: 1px 1px indigo;">
      <li class="tab" onclick="music()">
          <img id="musicIcon" src="images/musicOff.svg" width="32" height="32">
      </li>
  </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I really appreciate it, I'll most likely be using your method.